# TypeORM Apollo nested query resolver

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo-server, typeorm

I have a schema (with the appropriate database tables and entity classes defined) like

```
type User {
    id: Int!
    phoneNumber: String!
}

type Event {
    id: Int!
    host: User
  }
```

and I'm trying to use Apollo to write a query like

```
Query{
  event(id:1){
    host{
      firstName
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get the Apollo library to resolve the User type in the host field to the hostId that is stored on the event object.

I modified the event to return the hostId field, and it works perfectly fine, but Graphql won't resolve the id to the appropriate user type.  What am I missing?

edit: missing resolver code

```
event: async (parent: any, args: { id: number }) => {
      const eventRepository = getConnection().getRepository(Event);
      const event = await eventRepository.findOne(args.id);
      return event;
    },
```

I managed to get a working version by using `findOne(args.id, { relations: ['host']})`, but I don't like that because it seems like something that would be appropriate to delegate to graphql to handle.

Comment: Please include the relevant resolver code.

Answer (score 2):

Your resolver should be like that

```
const resolver = {

Query: {
    event: async (_: any, args: any) => {
      return await event.findOne(args.id);
    }
  },
  event: {
    host: async (parent: any, args: any, context: any) => {
      return await user.find({ id: parent.id });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using graphql?  If I have to manually code all these nested cases, I'm no better off than when I was using REST.

Comment: @BrandonOlivier did you find an answer to this? I am facing the same issue - having to map out every single nested case.

Comment: I'm afraid I ended up bailing on GraphQL to speed up my project.

Comment: @BrandonOlivier I don't think that's accurate. With a REST endpoint you'd probably have to do multiple API calls to get the event and user associated with that event whereas with GraphQL you'd just do one.

In regards to your question, you may not have to create a resolver for the user. If there a database relationship with the event you can retrieve the event-user relation. That may be the most efficient if user is always called with event.